# Definition of independent set of functions on an interval

Tags: linear-algebra, wronskian

A set of functions $\{f_1 , f_2 ,...... , f_n \}$  is called linearly independent on an Interval iff following condition holds.

$\sum_i^n c_i f_i(\alpha) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in I$ iff $c_i=0$ for all $i$.

Can anyone tell me if I have gone wrong anywhere ?

Comment: Not worth to write an answer so I'll write it here: after the correction your definition is fine assuming that all $f_i$'s are distinct. Otherwise look up the [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition) between a linearly independent sequence and linearly independent set.

Comment: You don't need to assume the $f_i$ are distinct. His definition is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would alter the definition to the following.

A set of distinct functions $$\{f_1,f_2,......,f_n\}$$ is called linearly independent on an Interval iff following condition holds.

$$∑_{i=1}^n c_i f_i(x)\equiv 0  \iff c_i=0 , 1\le i\le n.$$

Comment: To me this looks worse than the original. It's also incorrect unless we assume the $f_i$'s are distinct.

Comment: Why is this worse than the original?

Comment: What is the error in my definition ? @MohammadRiazi-Kermani

Comment: You have for any $\alpha \in I $ which should be for all $\alpha \in I $

Comment: Edited @MohammadRiazi-Kermani

Comment: Because it differs from the original by replacing the clear "for any $\alpha \in I$" with a less clear "$\equiv 0$" and the elegantly worded "for all $i$" with two inequalities after a comma. I agree that "all" is better than "any" here. But then again - instead of either you have the dubious "$\equiv$".

Comment: Can you write your definition ?@Adayah

Comment: Can we get a number $\alpha \in I$ such that $\sum c_i f_i(\alpha) =0$ with all $c_i$ are not $0$ when we know the set of functions is independent on $I$ ?@MohammadRiazi-Kermani

Comment: Can we get a number $\alpha \in I$ such that $\sum c_i f_i(\alpha) =0$ with all $c_i$ are not $0$ when we know the set of functions is independent on $I$ ?@Adayah

Comment: $f_1(x)=x$ and $ f_2(x)= x^2$, $\alpha =1 $ take $c_1=1$ and $c_2=-1$

Comment: If $y_1(x) , y_2(x)$ are two independent solutions of the differential equation $a_0(x)y''(x)+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_2(x)y(x)=0$ , then there does not exist any $\alpha$ such that $y_0(\alpha) = y_1(\alpha) = y_2(\alpha) = 0$  where $\alpha \in I$. Can you please tell me why this statement is correct ?@MohammadRiazi-Kermani

Comment: uinqueness of solutions.